# Android how to position TabLayout to the bottom of the screen (for Google's material design library TabLayout)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I am trying to use a TabLayout joined with a ViewPager to create three swipeable fragments. However, I ran against a problem: **I want the TabLayout to be at the bottom of the screen, but the ViewPager is forcing it to be at the top**.

TabLayout used to be in the *android.support.design.widget* library. This library, however, has been changed since androidx was introduced. The new library is *com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout*.

Previous (and outdated) posts ([example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41481536/android-tablayout-on-the-bottom-of-the-screen), [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34871848/tablayout-position-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen)) suggest a simple solution to the above problem by simply creating a vertical `LinearLayout` and specifying the `ViewPager` and `TabLayout` as two separate elements of that `LinearLayout`.

The above solution is no longer viable due to the fact that now, you have to specify the `TabLayout` to be an element inside of the `ViewPager` ([reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view)), like this:

```
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        >
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
</androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
```

Then, to "merge" the `ViewPager` with the `TabLayout`, the `setupWithViewPager(ViewPager vp)` method has to be called on the `TabLayout` instance:

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
MainPagerAdapter mpa = new MainPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 3);
viewPager.setAdapter(mpa);

TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

**Now, how can I neatly make the TabLayout go to the bottom of the ViewPager, either from xml code or programmatically?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set android TabLayout in the bottom of the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33380668/how-to-set-android-tablayout-in-the-bottom-of-the-screen)

Answer (score 6):

I've found an answer: simpy add the `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` to the `TabLayout` in xml.

So the xml implementation now looks like:

```
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            >
        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
```

Comment: Great work thank you , this should be the answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to your reference - To include a TabLayout in a ViewPager, add a TabLayout element inside of the ViewPager element.

but it doesn't mean you cannot use TabLayout outside ViewPager.
so you can use any answers from previous posts
or you can try like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tab_layout"/>

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="48dp"/></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Found a simpler solution... check my answer :D